# Retrieving Data in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, web-scraping, data-extraction

I'm a java novice. Is it possible to get data from a website and then store it in some sort of data structure? For example, the program gets the value of a stock from yahoo finance at a given time and stores it. Like I said, I'm not that proficient with Java and I'd like to know if this could be done. If it can be, is it very hard to do it?

Comment: Yes, it can be done, yes it is difficult (from your perceptive).  You will need to understand such things like how to deal with a `URLConnection`, basic I/O & `String` parsing to start with.  You might even need to understand JDBC.  With some experience, no, it's not hard.  I'd start with some basics though.  Try reading a HTML file of your local drive.  Once you understand the basic of `String` parsing, try downloading it.

Comment: You are talking about web scraping. There is a good library in Java which can help you do this, called JSoup.

Comment: the chances are, the site you are trying to get it from already has programmatically much more easly retrieved web services that you can crawl without arduous HTML parsing

Answer (score 3):

```
    public class GetYahooData
    {
        public ArrayList<JSONObject> getOutputFromUrl(String url) 
        {
            ArrayList<JSONObject> output = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
            JSONObject myjson ;
            JSONArray the_json_array;
            try 
            {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                char[] buf = new char[8000];
                int l = 0;
                    while (l >= 0) 
                    {
                        builder.append(buf, 0, l);
                        l = in.read(buf);
                    }
                myjson = new JSONObject("{child:"+builder.toString()+"}");
                JSONObject mmm = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                JSONArray mmmArr = mmm.getJSONArray("status");
                the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("child");
                for (int i = 0; i < the_json_array.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject another_json_object =  the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);//the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    output.add(another_json_object);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                System.out.println("ClientProtocolException :"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException :"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("JSONException hussain :"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output;
        }
    }

public class useYahoo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String url = "the url you want the response from";
        getYahooData object = new GetYahooData();
        ArrayList<JSONObject> output = object.getOutputFromUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) extensively. If you only need to customize a program to extract data from a website whose layout or structure does not change often, `JSoup` would be enough and handy.

Assuming you know the basics about how to program(not necessarily familiar with `Java`) and understand what constitutes the Web(e.g., what is `html`,`dom`,etc), I'd expect you to pick up how to do Web scraping with `JSoup` pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can download arbitrary web page into a Java string and parse the contents, however such solution wouldn't be reliable. If the author changes the structure of the website your code would immediately break.

Popular way of doing such integration is by [RESTful web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). The data provider would have a set of URL & parameters which you can call, and returns the stock price data (in xml or JSON format)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with the help of webservice.

1. Yahoo or other will expose webservices.
2. Your program will consume that webservice and will fetch the data and do manipulation at your end