# Java Performing Actions on a Website

Tags: java

Yesterday I posted this [Retrieving Data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103944/retrieving-data-in-java) . I'm curious it is possible to make a java program run while a web browser is open and then have it do stuff on a website. If I have facebook open on a browser, could it type the current time in the status box and then click post? Or let's say I make the program able to take input from the user (perhaps using scanner?) and then based on the input, it could load google, type it into the search bar and then click search.

Comment: Sure. Sounds like you'll want to use the API's of mentioned sites to do the work "in the background".

Comment: This sounds like webbrowser automation

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/):

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it. What you do with that power is
>   entirely up to you. Primarily it is for automating web applications
>   for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.
>   Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be
>   automated as well.

This is example from [documentation page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) which searches for the term “Cheese” on Google:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```